# Using button to create draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

I'm using .draggable to create a div (post it note) that is draggable, but I can't seem to figure out how to make each element draggable. Here is my create div function. How can I create a button that will create draggable divs? Thanks!

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
     });


function createDiv() {
        var yellowButton = document.getElementById("yellowColor");
        var greenButton = document.getElementById("greenColor");
        var blueButton = document.getElementById("blueColor");
        var purpleButton = document.getElementById("purpleColor");



        var newNote = document.createElement('div');
        if (yellowButton.checked) {
            document.getElementById('theText1').innerHTML = document.getElementById("textOfNote").value;
            newNote.innerHTML = document.getElementById('yellowNote').innerHTML;
            document.body.appendChild(newNote);
            newNote.style.display = "inline-block";
            newNote.id="draggable";

        } 
        if (greenColor.checked) {
            document.getElementById('theText2').innerHTML = document.getElementById("textOfNote").value;
            newNote.innerHTML = document.getElementById('greenNote').innerHTML;
            document.body.appendChild(newNote);
            newNote.style.display = "inline-block";


        } 
        if(blueColor.checked) {
            document.getElementById('theText3').innerHTML = document.getElementById("textOfNote").value;
            newNote.innerHTML = document.getElementById('blueNote').innerHTML;
            document.body.appendChild(newNote);
            newNote.style.display = "inline-block";


        }
        if(purpleColor.checked) {
            document.getElementById('theText4').innerHTML = document.getElementById("textOfNote").value;
            newNote.innerHTML = document.getElementById('purpleNote').innerHTML;
            document.body.appendChild(newNote);
            newNote.style.display = "inline-block";


        }
```

Comment: can you add your HTML ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1no67erk/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1no67erk/1/

Comment: does this work? Basically I am trying to use the button to create a draggable div, based on the radio button the user selected, and with the content the user entered, but I don't know how to add this functionality.

Comment: yes, this should work. I'll see if I can come up with a solution of any kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/)'s draggable method to achieve this. Just apply the class `.draggable` to your created notes, and apply:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
  containment: "document"
});
```

To make all elements with the `class="draggable"` draggable.

See working example:

```js
function createDiv() {
  var yellowButton = document.getElementById("yellowColor");
  var greenButton = document.getElementById("greenColor");
  var blueButton = document.getElementById("blueColor");
  var purpleButton = document.getElementById("purpleColor");



  var newNote = document.createElement('div');
  if (yellowButton.checked) {
    document.getElementById('theText1').innerHTML = document.getElementById("textOfNote").value;
    newNote.innerHTML = document.getElementById('yellowNote').innerHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(newNote);
    newNote.style.display = "inline-block";
    newNote.className = "ui-widget-content";

  }
  if (greenColor.checked) {
    document.getElementById('theText2').innerHTML = document.getElementById("textOfNote").value;
    newNote.innerHTML = document.getElementById('greenNote').innerHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(newNote);
    newNote.style.display = "inline-block";


  }
  if (blueColor.checked) {
    document.getElementById('theText3').innerHTML = document.getElementById("textOfNote").value;
    newNote.innerHTML = document.getElementById('blueNote').innerHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(newNote);
    newNote.style.display = "inline-block";


  }
  if (purpleColor.checked) {
    document.getElementById('theText4').innerHTML = document.getElementById("textOfNote").value;
    newNote.innerHTML = document.getElementById('purpleNote').innerHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(newNote);
    newNote.style.display = "inline-block";


  }
  newNote.classList.add('draggable');
  $('.draggable').draggable({
    containment: "document"
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>
  .draggable {
    cursor: move;
  }
  #yellowNoteStyle {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    background: #FDFB8C;
    border: 1px solid #DEDC65;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  
  #greenNoteStyle {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    background: #A5F88B;
    border: 1px solid #98E775;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  
  #blueNoteStyle {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    background: #A6E3FC;
    border: 1px solid #75C5E7;
    margin: 10px;
  }
</style>
<center>
  <h1> Your virtual corkboard!</h1>
</center>



<legend>Welcome admin! </legend>
<fieldset>
  <section id="addnote">
    <div>
      <center>
        <form action="mainpage.php" method="post">
          <h3> What do you want the note to say? </h3>
          <textarea id="textOfNote"></textarea>
          <br/>
          <b> Choose Note Color </b>
          <br/>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td> <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" id="yellowColor" /> </td>
              <td> <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" id="greenColor" /> </td>
              <td> <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" id="blueColor" /> </td>
              <td> <input type="radio" name="color" value="purple" id="purpleColor" /> </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <div id="yellowNoteStyle"> </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div id="greenNoteStyle"> </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div id="blueNoteStyle"> </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style="width:100px;  height: 100px; background:#c58cf7; border: 1px solid #75C5E7;margin: 0 auto;width: 100px;"> </div>
              </td>

            </tr>

          </table>
          <br/>



        </form>
      </center>
    </div>


    <div id="create">
      <button onClick="createDiv()">Insert onto the Corkboard</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<br>

<div id="yellowNote" style="display: none;">
  <div id="yellowNoteStyle" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p><span id='theText1'></span></p>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="greenNote" style="display: none;">
  <div id="greenNoteStyle" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p><span id='theText2'></span></p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="blueNote" style="display: none;">
  <div id="blueNoteStyle" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p><span id='theText3'></span></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: No worries!! Glad to help

Comment: @Sansan Hi, yes there is a way for you to do this, but it would require you to use some php and ajax like you said. So, once the user has logged in you can update their database record anytime they create a new note. `stop: function( event, ui ) {}` you can also add this property to update the positions of the notes in the database everytime you move a note to a new position. I've only used ajax briefly in the past so I'm not an expert in the area, I suggest that you maybe open a new question highlighting what you've tried to far and what you're trying to do :)

Comment: Yeah, you can also look into using *localStorage* to achieve this. Using a database would probably be the most straight-forward way.